# Java calculation with ints and longs returns different values with or without parentheses. Why?

Tags: java, int, long-integer

This is a simple example of the problem:

```
public class IntVsLong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 3;
        int b = 3;
        long n = 549382313570L;
        String s = "epsxyyflvrrrxzvnoenvpegvuonodjoxfwdmcvwctmekpsnamchznsoxaklzjgrqruyzavshfbmuhdwwmpbkwcuomqhiyvuztwvq";

        System.out.println(a * n/s.length() + b); //returns 16481469410
        System.out.println(a * (n/s.length()) + b); //returns 16481469408
    }

}
```

The first situation, without parentheses, returns 16481469410. The second one, with parentheses, returns 16481469408. Why?

Comment: Because you changed the order of evaluation.

Comment: Hello. I think this is a math problem... Your parentheses changed the order of calculation.

Comment: @takendarkk As far as I know, Java follows math rules and there should be no difference if I multiply a with n before dividing by s.length() VS first dividing n with s.length() and then multiplying with a. b is added last in both situations. Also the difference in the two results is only 2, it would have been much more different if I had first added b and than did the operations. Please reread the code or explain with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because order of evaluation is different, and integer math rounds down. For an example with smaller numbers to show the point.

```
3 * (5 / 2) = 3 * (2) = 6
```

without parentheses

```
3 * 5 / 2 = 15 / 2 = 7
```

operations are evaluated left to right without parentheses, and when you reach the division statement, you lose some information because integers cannot hold fractional numbers. The earlier you lose this information *in general* the less accurate your final result.

Comment: "and integer math rounds down" is really the crucial bit, so your answer should give it top billing, imo.

Comment: @rtpax Ah there's the answer "integer math rounds down". Thank you, this is what I was missing from understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If both operands are of integer type, / operator in Java represents integer division, meaning that division reminder is discarded. In your case difference between results is 2, meaning that reminder of `n/s.length()` operation is greater than `2 / a` and obviously less than 1. So in case of `a * n/s.length()` this reminder is multiplied by `a` and gives you that excess 2 in the answer.

Comment: “/ operator in Java represents integer division” …and also floating point division.  The use of `/` in itself is not the error, it’s the use of integral operands that is.